# One to one relationship with special case Sqlalchamy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am designing a database where user is super class and Customer and Admin are inheriting User class. So according to the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html) in SQL SQLAlchemy I define like this

User Class

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    username = Column(String(40), primary_key=True)
    is_verified = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    type = Column(String(20), nullable=True)
    password = Column(String(40))
    first_name = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    image_url = Column(String(250), nullable=True)
    email = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    phone = Column(String(15), nullable=True)
    addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")
    customer = relationship("Customer", uselist=False, back_populates="user")
    admin = relationship("Admin", uselist=False, back_populates="user")

    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.password = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password)
```

Customer Class

```
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(40), ForeignKey('user.username'))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="customer")
    products = relationship("Review")
    cart = relationship("Cart", uselist=False, back_populates="customer")
```

Admin Class

```
class Admin(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'admin'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(20), ForeignKey('user.username'))
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="admin")
```

The problem is User and Customer are one to one , User and Admin are one to one . but I defied admin and customer in the user class.

Further when I delete user it's not deleting the customer automatically.

What is the proper way to implement this scenario ?

Comment: To get the `Customer` and `Admin` instances to automatically delete you need to specify [`ondelete="CASCADE"`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey.params.ondelete) to the `ForeignKey` constructor. I don't understand what the rest of your question is pertaining to.

Comment: @SuperShoot It didn't solve at all . Thanks

Comment: You'd have to re-create the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `cascade="save-update, merge, delete"`

The delete cascade indicates that when a “parent” object is marked for deletion, its related “child” objects should also be marked for deletion. If for example, we have a relationship User.addresses with delete cascade configured

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    username = Column(String(40), primary_key=True)
    is_verified = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    type = Column(String(20), nullable=True)
    password = Column(String(40))
    first_name = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    image_url = Column(String(250), nullable=True)
    email = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    phone = Column(String(15), nullable=True)
    addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")
    customer = relationship("Customer", uselist=False, back_populates="user",cascade="save-update, merge, delete")
    admin = relationship("Admin", uselist=False, back_populates="user",cascade="save-update, merge, delete")

    def hash_password(self, password):
        self.password = pwd_context.encrypt(password)

    def verify_password(self, password):
        return pwd_context.verify(password, self.password)
```